# bucle de secuencia en el que sumas el las veces indicadas en un input como por ejemplo; input =50: 1

Tags: bucles, input

yo tengo un input al que no le puedo poner un rango de numeros del 50 al 100 y se crean x grupos segun el numero puesto,ej: 1+2+3=6 6+7+8=21 siempre siguiendo la secuencia del resultado de la suma de los 3 numero de la secuencia.

Comment: Buenas, Raúl, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? No está clara cual es tu pregunta exacta. ¿En qué lenguaje estás programando? ¿Qué tienes hecho hasta ahora, cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál es el que estás obteniendo actualmente? Por favor, edita tu pregunta con todos esos detalles.